# How to remove distractions like related posts from Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion

I am easily distracted and want to only go to Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites to solve a specific problem, however my eyes constantly go to "Linked" or "Related" or "Hot Meta Posts".
Is there a way to *only* show the search bar, questions and answers and nothing else?

Comment: @John: This is not an answer to my question.

Comment: Some ad blockers can remove entire sections of any page. I used to do similar on SE, but current Safari will not allow that type of extension any more.

Answer (score 3):

- In your browser, install *uBlock Origin* add-on.
- Right-click on a page element and select *Block element*.
- Click *Preview* to see how the page looks with that element blocked.
- Click *Create* to create a rule to block that in the future.

You may need to block *multiple* elements, as some may be hidden under others, as containers.

This tool is particularly useful for sites with annoying overlays, such as YouTube.

[image: uBlock Origin - blocking an element]